# Getting `POST requests require a Content-length header. ' when running Curl code

Tags: php, curl, oauth, header, token

I want to get an Auth2 token through this curl request:

```
define("CALLBACK_URL", "http://localhost/los/index");
define("AUTH_URL", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
define("ACCESS_TOKEN_URL", "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");
 define("CLIENT_ID", "**.apps.googleusercontent.com");
define("CLIENT_SECRET", "**");
define("SCOPE", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos"); // optional


 function getToken(){
 $curl = curl_init();

 $params = array(
CURLOPT_URL =>  ACCESS_TOKEN_URL."?"
                ."code=".$code
                ."&grant_type=authorization_code"
                ."&client_id=". CLIENT_ID
                ."&client_secret=". CLIENT_SECRET
                ."&redirect_uri=". CALLBACK_URL,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => false, 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  "cache-control: no-cache",
  "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "accept: *",
  "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
),
 );

  curl_setopt_array($curl, $params);


   $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $err = curl_error($curl);
  echo $response;
  curl_close($curl);

  if ($err) {
   echo "cURL Error #01: " . $err;
       } else {
 $response = json_decode($response, true);    
    if(array_key_exists("access_token", $response)) return $response;
if(array_key_exists("error", $response)) echo $response["error_description"];
echo "cURL Error #02: Something went wrong! Please contact admin.";
  }
 }
```

However, it gives me this error message: 
`POST requests require a Content-length header. That’s all we know.`

Ive tried to remove the newlines in the URL but that did not resolve it. (I followed [this](http://tutorialspage.com/simple-oauth2-example-using-php-curl/) tutorial)
How can I fix this? Do I need to put the content-length header manually?

Comment: Add a `Content-Length` header to you `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER ` array.

Comment: what would be the value in this structure? As I have no POSTFIELDS parameter

Comment: Usually the size of the body (in bytes). Since you don't have any, I'd suggest trying 0 as a value.

Comment: That did the trick can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Sure, posted it as an answer.

Comment: @Y_Lakdime : your comment is very usefull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `Content-Length` header to your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` array.

The value usually is the size of the body (in bytes). Since you don't have any, I'd suggest trying 0 as a value.

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  "cache-control: no-cache",
  "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "accept: *",
  "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
  "Content-Length: 0"
)
```